# Help Needed- what's wrong with my plant

Tags: indoors

Any ideas whats going on and how to fix it?
The plant has been fine for over years and recently developed brown spots on the stems and edges of the fronds are brown some have dark spots /yellow in the center

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

Too much or not enough water for your palm.Make sure you have the proper pot, drainage and light. Maybe a re-potting is in order also. I have a smaller palm in my bathroom. If I let it get dry the fronds will turn brown. Good Luck